# How to resize a PictureBox while maintaining its Aspect Ratio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Windows Forms application where I let the user resize a PictureBox. But it's pretty useless because it does not maintain its aspect ratio as the user makes it smaller or larger.

How can I do this? I know how to resize a picturebox normally with mouseDown, mouseMove and mouseUp events, but how to make sure it keeps its aspect ratio?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change `SizeMode = Zoom` on the `PictureBox`. That will keep the aspect ratio for your image.

The only side-effect you may not want is that it will also make the image larger than the original, if you increase the size of the form enough, resulting in a fuzzy looking image.

Comment: Thanks @Grant. I will handle the mouseUp event to change it to its largest size if they make it bigger than it should be.

Comment: After all these years playing around with Controls in Win forms, I've never seen MaximumSize! Amazing lol

Comment: Also make sure your image is set on the Image property of the PictureBox, not the InitialImage or the BackgroundImage

Answer (score 3):

You can make the IMAGE inside the PictureBox to keep it aspect ratio... using SizeMode = Zoom

The PictureBox can be resized to any size, but the image will kept its aspect ratio within the PictureBox boundaries.